# Zero width caret navigation UTF8 character

Tags: unicode

Is there such a character, like the text-cursor/caret-navigation, the one that blinks when focusing text-areas?
a **zero-width** char of a vertical line?

Comment: Duplicate, but on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/548862/is-there-a-text-caret-unicode-character

Comment: Nope MSalters, that's a **mouse** text cursor asked about, not the blinking text caret.

Comment: The request is self-contradictory: a character that has zero width has no glyph, even a vertical line with thickness of one pixel. And there are no blinking characters in Unicode. Moreover, the shape of the cursor is browser-dependent.

Comment: Try asking a question that explains what you need, rather an assumed solution. What would you *use* the character for? Do you need a character, rather than e.g. some border (specified at a higher protocol level, e.g. in formatting instructions or in CSS).

Comment: Jukka, there are characters that has no width, but are visible - such as diacritics and combining characters.

Comment: To your question why: I want to use a textarea in mobile devices, without native keyboard popping out. So in order to do that I'm gonna use the textarea in readonly mode, that doesnt show the caret. I wanna show it. 
It is working, I'm using "|" charecter. but it pushes the text a little, and it breaks connected chars in other languages such as arabic. 

I thought that a solution would be to find a character that doesn't can't be showed without effecting the text. the closest one that if found is: U+0338, but it crosses the last char.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's a trivial shape to recognize, and yet [ShapeCatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) doesn't find anything close.

It's not a character you'd expect in a document, either. There are some dubious non-character code points in Unicode, but those exist for compatibility with legacy encodings. And I'm not familiar with any legacy code set that encoded that.

Comment: Thanks, true it is probably doesn't exist... thanks.

In that case I'm looking for a hack, I found this charecter: U+0338 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character , which is zero width char of a vertical diagonal line that goes **overlay** on the last char. 

So I'm looking for something similar, but not between the letters...